# Bootstrap pull div in medium screen not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 3 divs per row and I just want to move last div to top and move second div to bottom and make full width in mediums devices. Please take a look at image.

[image]

I tried with bootstrap push pull classes but no luck. What am I missing here?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
      <span>Test 1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-push-6 col-sm-12">
      <span>Test 2</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-pull-6 col-sm-6">
      <span>Test 3</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

span{
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  display: block;
}
```

[Jsfilddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lz59gyfo/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily do this if you migrate to the last version of bootstrap using `order` (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/#order)

```css
body {
    margin: 10px;
}

span{
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
      <span>Test 1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 order-sm-1 col-sm-12">
      <span>Test 2</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4  col-sm-6">
      <span>Test 3</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also like this if you want to keep the order for `md`

```css
body {
    margin: 10px;
}

span{
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 order-md-0 col-sm-6">
      <span>Test 1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 order-sm-1 col-sm-12">
      <span>Test 2</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 order-md-2  col-sm-6">
      <span>Test 3</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

Using Boostrap 3 you can try this:

```css
body {
  margin: 10px;
}

span {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  display: block;
}

@media all and (min-width:767px) and (max-width:992px) {
  /*make the sm-6 inline-block and the float will move to the bottom*/
  .special .col-sm-6 {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none!important;
  }
  /*fix white space issue of inline-block*/
  .special {
    font-size: 0;
  }
  .special * {
    font-size: initial;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row special">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
      <span>Test 1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4  col-sm-12">
      <span>Test 2</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
      <span>Test 3</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works well. But I'm using bootstrap 3

Comment: @Janath so probably the time to move to the 4 :) not sure if you can do this properly with 3

Comment: I'm at the end of development. So I can't shift now :(

Comment: @Janath ok will add a hacky way ;)

Comment: Bootstrap 3 in many cases plays along nicely, if the `row` container is just made into a `flex` ... equal height columns for example can be implemented quite easily using that, in most cases. Adding it to make `order` work should do the trick in this situation here as well, https://jsfiddle.net/8xyswtph/

Comment: @04FS but this may break the layout of boostrap. If we need to change to flex container than better change to boostrap 4 that is using flex to avoid issues.

Comment: @TemaniAfif but as I said, in many cases it doesn’t. Plus it could easily be applied to a specific section only in a case like this, it doesn’t need to be applied to every row everywhere. Switching to BS 4 might be an option if this is a new project, but if more around the snippet that we’ve been shown exists already, that might require additional time and effort … just saying, I don’t think BS3 necessarily prevents solving this with flexbox in this particular instance.

Answer (score 0):

Hope I understood the question correctly and if so is this the desired solution?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      <span>Test 1</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      <span>Test 3</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
      <span>Test 2</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No. I don't want to change the column order.